# CredentialCache and HttpWebRequest in .NET

Tags: c#, http, authentication

I'm having difficulty understanding how web requests and credentials work in .NET.

I have the following method that is executing a request to a SOAP endpoint.

```
 public WebResponse Execute(NetworkCredential Credentials)
 {
       HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, actionUrl);
       webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
       webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
       webRequest.Credentials = Credentials; 

       // Add headers and content into the requestStream

       asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
       return webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
}
```

It works well enough. However, users of my applications may have to execute dozens of these requests in short succession. Hundreds over the course of the day. My goal is to implement some of the recommendations I've read about, namely [using an HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) that exists for the entire lifetime of the application, and to use the [CredentialCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache?view=netframework-4.7.2) to store user's credentials, instead of passing them in to each request.

So I'm starting with the `CredentialCache`.

Following the example linked above, I instantiated a `CredentialCache` and added my network credentials to it. Note that this is the exact same `NetworkCredential` object that I was passing to the request earlier.

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential();
credential.UserName = Name;
credential.Password = PW;
Program.CredCache.Add(new Uri("https://blah.com/"), "Basic", credential);
```

Then, when I go to send my HTTP request, I get the credentials from the cache, instead of providing the credentials object directly.

```
 public WebResponse Execute(NetworkCredential Credentials)
 {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, actionUrl);
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        webRequest.Credentials = Program.CredCache; 

        // more stuff down here
}
```

The request now fails with a 401 error.

I am failing to understand this on several levels. For starters, I can't seem to figure out whether or not the `CredentialCache` has indeed passed the proper credentials to the HTTP request.

I suspect part of the problem might be that I'm trying to use "Basic" authentication. I tried "Digest" as well just as a shot in the dark (which also failed), but I'm sure there must be a way to see what kind of authentication the server is expecting.

I have been combing StackOverflow and MDN trying to read up as much as possible about this, but I am having a difficult time separating the relevant information from the outdated and irrelevant information.

If anyone can help me solve the problem that would be most appreciated, but even links to proper educational resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the `CredentialCache` class is only for SMTP, it explicitly says that it is not for HTTP or FTP requests:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache(v=vs.110).aspx

Which directly contradicts the info in the later api docs. Which one is right I don't know.

You could try using the `HttpClient` class. The methods and return types are different, so you would need to tweak your other a code a bit, but it would look a bit like this:

```
public class CommsClass
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CommsClass(NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
         var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
         _httpclient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Execute(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(message).Result;
        return response;
    }
}
```

You can do all sorts of other things with the handler, and the client like set request headers or set a base address.